# OpenCV and SVM training for luggages detection

Tags: opencv, classification, svm, libsvm, training-data

In my project, I am trying to differenciate a luggage from anything else, usually a human.

For the moment, I use OpenCV and SVM training method with 2 classes, one with luggages, and another one with humans. Before injecting the frames, I converted them to grayscale, but I don't apply additional filters. The result of the prediction is not very accurate.

I am wondering if applying additional filters to the frames before training might give a better result. For example contours detection. If the contour is close to a 'rectangle' then it is a luggage otherwise it is 'something else'. I am also thinking about switching to a ONE_CLASS method.

What do you think ? Or do you have better ideas ?

Regards,

Julien.

Comment: Your suggestion about '**approximate rectangles being luggage**' is a good place to start. You can then perform **anomaly detection**

Comment: what about training your own object detector with darknet? Take a look at this: http://pjreddie.com/darknet/yolo/

Comment: Contour probably wouldn't be a viable idea in this case. Have you tried fine-tuning the [SVM parameters](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/doc/tutorials/ml/introduction_to_svm/introduction_to_svm.html)? If by changing them in a wide range doesn't change the results much, go for better/robust features.

Comment: Thank you everybody for your answers ! About the SVM parameters. I am wondering if the training takes the colour into account. Do I need to inject all kind of colours into the SVM ?
About Darknet, I haven't tried yet, I will git it a try !
Right now I am investigating the following solution: removing the background (not sure about it), dilating and eroding to remove the 'noise', finding the contours, and applying a convex hull algorithm. Then I am thinking about doing the difference between the contour area and the hull area. If it is close, I assume it is a luggage, otherwise a human.

Answer (score 0):

After giving much thought regarding the question, I think **Anomaly Detection** is the best way to go. I got that idea since you mentioned `ONE_CLASS method`.

Assuming that luggage is of rectangular shape in an image, your suggestion of "anything close to rectangle is a luggage", is also a viable approach. Hence you have only one class 'Luggage'.

As the term implies, 'anomaly detection' is used to detect objects that do not conform to a particular pattern. In other words, it is used to detect ***outliers*** (objects other than those present in the dataset).

Since you are emphasizing on luggage alone I presume this approach to be the best.

You could try other approaches as well, in case you come across any.

Answer (score 0):

So the rectangle approximation method seems to fit my requirements. I haven't tested with a lot of images yet, so I am not 100% sure I'll go for it. As always, there is exceptions: when the color of the luggage is close to the color of the background, the result is not accurate. Is there a way to amplify the difference between two close colors ?

Regards,

Julien.